# .htaccess Rewrite URL instead of Redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Is it possible to Do this rewrite without it redirecting?

```
# redirect for the blog link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^topgearsblog/?$ http://aerogearblog.wordpress.com/ [NC,L]
```

I've tried it like:

```
# redirect for the blog link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^topgearsblog/?$ http://myblog.wordpress.com/ [L,QSA,NC]
```

and it still redirects instead of rewrites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible only if you enable [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) in you Apache config. Once it is enabled you can do:

```
# redirect for the blog link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^topgearsblog/?$ http://aerogearblog.wordpress.com/ [NC,L,P]
```

Comment: is there a way I can check if this is enabled?   Something like: `<ifModule mod_proxy.c>`

Comment: You can check with `phpinfo();` output.

Comment: yeah, not allowd to do that (security issues on that server, with people getting tmi)

Comment: on another note, this did work...  but, the blog is a wordpress.com blog and not self-hosted, so it is causing issues with scripts/images/css loading correctly...   ah well, back to the drawing board.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome. Yes I know, you can enable mod_proxy on the hosts in your control.